# flex not working to make design responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, flexbox, material-design

I am using React Material components in my application, to make it responsive to various screen sizes i am trying to use `flex`. Below is my code

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
     <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: "25%" }}>
      <Chip />
     </div>
    <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: "25%" }}>
      <Chip />
     </div>
   <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: "25%" }}>
      <Chip />
    </div>
   <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, flexBasis: "25%" }}>
      <Chip />
   </div>
 </div>
```

In the above code `Chip` is a component from `Material Ui`. The above code does not make the chips go down (responsive) as the screen size reduces. What's wrong?

Comment: You specified that all the element will be 25% of the container so they won't go down

Comment: @TemaniAfif Removing them not taking down as well. How  to correct?

Comment: specify a min-width

Comment: @TemaniAfif Updated the parent div to `   <div className={classes.flexContainer} style={{ flexWrap: "wrap", minWidth: '1600' }}>` still not working

Comment: min-width on the element, not the parent

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, my mistake, i updated it as `  <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, minWidth: '200'}}>` still its same..

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you please help me by giving an example on my shared code...thanks

Comment: check this:https://jsfiddle.net/x8soLfu5/ ..reduce the window size to see how the element will move to next lines