# Flex not making item responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, flexbox

I am using highcharts inside Flex to make it responsive across all screen sizes but its not becoming responsive for mobile screens. Below is my code in reactJs and issue is replicated at 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-s31oo

```
<div>
   <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" flexDirection="row">
   <Box m={0.5} style={{ flexBasis: "48%", minWidth: '0' }}>
     <LineChart
       chartData={ChartData}
     />
    </Box>
    <Box m={0.5} style={{ flexBasis: "48%", minWidth: '0' }}>
     <LineChart
       chartData={ChartData2}
     />
    </Box>            
    </Box>
  </div>
```

What's wrong in my design?

Comment: same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59141764/8620333 .. I would add the same comments

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the comment but i am not able to make my code correct..Could you please suggest me in my example..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you use `flexGrow: 1`

```
 <div>
        <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" flexDirection="row">
          <Box m={0.5} style={{ flexBasis: "48%", minWidth: "0", flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Chart chartData={options} />
          </Box>
          <Box m={0.5} style={{ flexBasis: "48%", minWidth: "0", flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Chart chartData={options} />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </div>
```